# How could i do to copy a file to a shared folder ( that shared folder is on server ) by using Windows service?

Tags: c#

When I ran:

```
File.Copy("c:\\temp.txt","\\\\192.168.0.1\\SharedFile\\temp.txt",True)
```

in windows application, it worked well. But when i used windows service, that code didn't work.

It seems that shared folder is not found when you use `path:"\\\\192.168.0.1\\SharedFile\\temp.txt"`. It seems that Windows Service 
will run under another desktop which is different from the logoned 
interactive desktop.

So how could i access shared folder by using windows service?

Comment: Windows services have a `logon as` property. Make sure you service's user has proper permission to the shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your service needs to run as a user that has permission to access that share. And also to run as a service, obviously. Normally you'd use a domain account to do this if there's a domain that both machines trust.